# If $A=5r^2$ and $\frac{dA}{du}=2$, what is $\frac{dr}{du}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am unsure exactly what this question is asking me to do. I think $\frac{dA}{dr} = 10r$ and I assume $u=a/2$ but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [chain rule of differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):

$$ \dfrac{dA}{du} = \dfrac{dA}{dr} \cdot \dfrac{dr}{du} \\
2 = 10 r \cdot \dfrac{dr}{du} $$

Thus, $ \dfrac{dr}{du} = (5r)^{-1} $